# How to edit a MS Word system macro

Tags: vba, ms-word, cjk

I use MS Word for Mac Version 16.45 with German as main language.
I want to write furigana in Japanese. This is possible by using Phonetic Guides.
However, this function has a well known bug (in Word for Mac only ). The furigana are positioned left above the kanji, even if you selected center position.

[image]

Selecting the field function of the kanji results in the lower string

```
{q \* jc2 \* "Font:UD Digi Kyokasho N-R" \* hps14 \o\ad(\s\up 13(しん),新)}
```

Changing the comma at the very end to a semicolon and deselecting the field function results in the correct result.

[image]

The VBA object catalog shows me, that the macro in charge is the **Range.PhoneticGuide-Methode**.
It seems to me, that the parameter **wdPhoneticGuideAlignmentCenter** is set to a wrong value.

Fixing this bug shouldn't be a big deal, but:

Is it possible to edit the Range.PhoneticGuide-Methode?
And where can I find the VBA code?

Comment: What do you mean  by "MS Word system macro"?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have written a macro to apply the Phonetic Guide there isn't a macro involved, so there isn't any VBA code to find.

If there is a bug then it is in Word and all you can do is report it to Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

You can't edit the method but you can use the method. Place the following in a VBA module in your Normal template and then you can execute it on the selection in your document.

```
Sub PhoneticGuide()
    Selection.Range.PhoneticGuide Text:="tray sheek", _
     Alignment:=wdPhoneticGuideAlignmentCenter, _
     Raise:=11, FontSize:=7
     
    'other alignment options
'     Alignment:=wdPhoneticGuideAlignmentLeft, _
'     Alignment:=wdPhoneticGuideAlignmentOneTwoOne, _
'     Alignment:=wdPhoneticGuideAlignmentRight, _
'     Alignment:=wdPhoneticGuideAlignmentRightVertical, _
'     Alignment:=wdPhoneticGuideAlignmentZeroOneZero, _

End Sub
```

I've included the available alignment options that you can experiment with to find the one that works for you. I copied the base code from the following Microsoft article, which you can use for further reference.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.range.phoneticguide