# Which VBA function or macro is called when pressed the "phonetic guide" button in MS Word or Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

In Word I use the "phonetic guide" button for adding furigana to a kanji.
After that I would like to post process the document.
The idea is to write a macro which calls the  "phonetic guide" function, which opens the window for entering the Japanese text in the the first step and do do the post processing in the second step.
I used the macro recording function to get the "phonetic guide" command.
However, the result is an empty function body.

How can I get the function name which is connected with the "phonetic guide" button?

Answer (score 0):

Open the VBA Editor (F11) and look it up in the Object Browser.

[image]

You can also look at the answer that was given to the last question that you asked on this subject, [How to edit a MS Word system macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65979761/how-to-edit-a-ms-word-system-macro)

Comment: This command doesn't open the Window which is open by pressing the menu button.

Comment: @HeinzM. - then you will need the dialog, which is the second result shown in the Object Browser.